# Wired network adapter doesn't function properly when starting Windows

Tags: power-management, network-adapter

Every time I start my computer, my wired network adapter stops working - this includes a cold start and resuming from sleep. If I head over to Network and Sharing Center and click Troubleshoot Problems, I am eventually able to get the adapter working again. Here is a screenshot of the last page of the troubleshooting wizard:

[image]

It would seem like something isn't configured properly and is preventing the network adapter driver from initializing. I've checked the power management settings and they look like this:

[image]

Machine information:

- Windows 8 Consumer Preview 32-bit
- Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller (according to Device Manager)

---

**Edit:** I found this in the event logs:

> "Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0x001DE09DCC29.  The following error occurred: 0x7B0000. Your computer will continue to try and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP) server."

Comment: Is it possible that the driver isn't fully compatible with Windows 8?

Comment: Any more detail in the event logs?

Comment: @DaveM: Yes, I have updated the question with the results.