# What setting did the troubleshooter change for "The default gateway is not available"?

Tags: windows-7

I was browsing the internet on a computer with windows 7 starter, then wasn't able to, but other computers on my network, other OSs, could.

On the  windows 7 starter one, I ran the troubleshooter, and it said

"The troubleshooter made some changes to your system. Try attempting the task you were trying to do before"
"The default gateway is not available" Fixed

Now I can browse again, though I don't know if i'll run into it again or the cause.

What changes did it make?

And what might've caused this problem?

Comment: Are your IP addresses for your computer set automatically (via DHCP)?

Comment: @iglvzx it is and while I can't vouch for how  it was set before, I'm pretty sure it was before too.  I could guess that perhaps it was some dhcp issue, but i've no idea how  it had it then suddenly could have forgotten.

Comment: somebody posted something with a link to this http://superuser.com/questions/415416/why-does-my-wireless-network-card-need-to-be-reset-everytime-i-start-or-wake-my  which may be a log from the troubleshooter though I don't see an entry on my computer for it.

Comment: lan connection..you can enable/disable(a good form of more manual fix), , view details(shows ip and other like ipconfig /all - shows gateway ip).. Also you can click diagnose, you can view detection details and it mentions a log though probably no more things there and it's not stored in plaintext.